# Speeding up a series of calculations across a large matrix in R

Tags: r, performance, math, matrix

Any suggestions, programmatically or mathematically, for speeding up this calculation in R? I have included some generated data that closely match the real data scenario that I am working with. I have also attempted to use apply and parApply and tried to turn it into a sparse matrix since it has so many 0's, but so far this is the fastest method I have come up with. Any suggestions for making it faster? I need to do this calculations 10,000's of times.

**Data that closely match my scenario:**

```
set.seed(7)
# same size matrix as my real data data puzzle
A <- matrix(rbeta((13163*13163),1,1), ncol = 13163, nrow = 13163)

# turn a bunch to 0 to more closely match that I have a lot of 0's in real data
A[A < 0.5] <- 0

# create binary matrix
z <- matrix(rbinom((13163*13163), 1, 0.25), ncol = 13163, nrow = 13163)
```

**I have found that Rfast::rowsums gives me the quickest results.**

```
start1 <- Sys.time()
testA <- 1 - exp(Rfast::rowsums(log(1-A*z)))
stop1 <- Sys.time()
stop1 - start1
```

Pardon my clunky benchmarking approach...

Comment: The matrices you provide are one-column matrices. Are you sure this is what you have?

Comment: [microbenchmark](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-the-microbenchmark-package-to-compare-the-execution-time-of-r-expressions/) is very, very easy to use (much easier than the annoying `timeit` module in Python, but I digress). No reason to go clunky.

Comment: Thank you @F.Privé. I fixed that typo and ask the same question but in the context of slightly different outcome (Sparse matrix was never quicker).

Answer (score 2):

You can get rid of `exp()` and `log()`:

```
testB <- 1 - Rfast::rowprods(1-A*z)
```

This is 8 times faster.

Yet, as you multiply many number between 0 and 1, you end up having 0s everywhere, so the output vector is all 1s..

Comment: Thanks! I am just learning about the Rfast package. However, you are correct this underflow issue is why I was going with the exp-sum-log approach.

Comment: Have I answered your question or were you expecting something else?

Comment: No, I am still trying to figure out if I can do this faster without the underflow issue.

Comment: Rfast::rowprods has a method argument for choosing the exp-sum method which is faster than R's.